# Need help in AngularJS deep filtering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I've been trying to filter an select with another based on this informations came from a web service:

```
{
    sections: [
        {
            st_id: '1',
            st_nm: 'name1',
            blocks: [
                {
                    bl_id: '1',
                    bl_nm: 'block1'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            st_id: '2',
            st_nm: 'name2',
            blocks: [
                {
                    bl_id: '2',
                    bl_nm: 'block2'
                },
                {
                    bl_id: '2-1',
                    bl_nm: 'block2-1'
                }
                // ... and so on
            ]
        }
        // ... and so on
    ]
}
```

I tried a lot of things and combinations, but I'm really new in Angular and nothing works. I need filter the second select, and fill with the "blocks" information, with the "st_nm" field selected in the first select element.

I'm grateful for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I know what you're trying to do here and here's my suggestion:

```
<select id="st_select" ng-model="st_selected" ng-options="sect.st_nm for sect in sections">

<select id="blocks_select" ng-model="block_selected" ng-options="block.b1_nm for block in st_selected.blocks">
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, did you know how can I make the option output be customized? I'd like to put more information than "bl_nm", I want something like this: <select><option>Block 2-1 ; Name block2-1</option></select>